# How do I merge a branch without deleting files?

Tags: git

In the Master branch, I deleted some unnecessary files (say d1.txt, d2.txt, d3.txt, ...).
These files are necessary for the Dev branch for some test features.
Now, if I merge the Master branch to the Dev branch, these files get deleted from the Dev branch too.

Manually restoring the deleted files is not a good option.
Is there a way to merge the Master branch to the Dev branch without deleting any files?

Comment: Sure... you merge with `--no-commit`, then do `git checkout HEAD -- file1 file2 file3` and then `git merge --continue` so that you wrap up the merge and then your files _won't be deleted_ by the merge.

Comment: @eftshift0 merge with --no-commit merged Master to Dev and deleted the files without any commit. I couldn't restore the files using "git checkout HEAD -- file1 file2". I had to find the commit on Dev before the merge and run "git reset --hard commit_id" to undo the merge.

Comment: @eftshift0 I just had to merged with --no-ff to fix the issue `git merge Dev --no-commit --no-ff`, and restore the files with `git checkout HeAD -- file1 file2 file3`

Comment: you could close the question since you solved it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I just had to merge with `--no-ff` to fix the issue

```
git merge Dev --no-commit --no-ff
```

and restore the files with

```
git checkout HeAD -- file1 file2 file3
```